# TWIG/Timber dump function leads to "fatal error"

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm trying to use the dump function as was advides by a bunch of people, so I could get a better hang of Timber/TWIG.

However when I try it i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "dump" function.
```

I am confused, since this should be included in Timber itsself.
Another thing is that ACF (Wordpress) functions don't seem to work.

Comment: As seen in the [documentation](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/docs/guides/debugging.md) you will have to enable `debug` first.

Comment: yes, enable debugging first, in your wp-config.php - define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: yeah, i already did that. @DarkBee

Comment: Then register the `Twig_Extension_Debug` manually to your `twig`-instance

Comment: How do you use the dump function exactly? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @Gchtr `{{ dump(var) }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enable the WP debug in *wp-config*.

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: That was literally 18 Months ago :P Way ahead now.
But thanks. Here you go for answering :P

Comment: @Frizzant Haha, yes I'm aware. Just answered to help those who will encounter the same problem in the future. :)